# UILabel with more... text

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I have a text with multiple lines but at the end I want to add the phrase "more..." if the user press the more... word than the system it suppose to display the rest of the paragraph.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141853/iphone-how-to-identify-whether-uilabels-will-show-truncated-text
this link will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

one way is: use a UILabel to display a short text
put a UIButton under that with "show more" make settings to button to look like a UILabel
catch the action of the button, and remove the button and display a multines text and change the size of the UILabel.

This isn't the right approach for novice programmers, I hope I have helped with an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UITextView that contains the limited text and add a UITapGestureRecognizer that when tapped, removes the gesture and adds text to the textview.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particularly easy way, built-in way to do it.  If you want to implement it yourself, your best bet is to use a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel`.  `UITextView` conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol, so when you detect a tap on the text view, you can use `closestPositionToPoint:` and related messages to figure out which part of the string was tapped.

Instead of doing it yourself, you could use [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) or [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).  Both of these have built-in support for detecting taps on links.  I haven't used either, so I can't advise you on which is better.  There are probably other free solutions available, but those were easy to find.